# Stuck with extended Euclidean algorithm.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Use the Euclidean algorithm to express $\text{gcd}(330, 156)$ as a linear combination of $330$ and $156$.

My working so far is as follows:

$330 = 2\times156 +18$

$156= 8\times18+12$

$18=1\times12+6$

$12=2\times6+0$

therefore, $\text{gcd}(330,156) =6$.

Rearranging the equations

$18= 330-156\times2$

$12=156-8\times18$

$6=18-1\times12$

$0=12-2\times6$

I have tried to utilise the back substitution method but truth be told, finding myself totally lost and confused by it; not to mention making numerous errors.

Comment: A variable $x$ is quite different from the multiplication symbol `\times`, rendered as $\times$...

Comment: yes, i am familiar with that.

Comment: @NEWSUN:  Your syntax might be more justifiable than the OP's, but it is better to give constructive criticism in Comments and let the OP take a decision about how best to Edit the Question.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep expressing the remainders as expressions involving the other numbers in your algorithm steps. So
\begin{align}
6&=18-12\cdot 1\\
&=18-(156-8\cdot18)\cdot1\\
&=9\cdot 18-156\\
&=9\cdot(330-2\cdot156)-156\\
&=9\cdot330-19\cdot156.
\end{align}

So, in the equation $330x+156y=6$; we have $x=9$ and $y=-19$.

Comment: Im sorry. I am lost as to how you got from 

=18-(156-8x18)x1 to

=9x18-156

Comment: No need to apologise. Expand the bracket; we have $$18-(156-8\cdot 18)$$ is equivalent to $$18-156+8\cdot 18,$$ since the two minus signs make a plus. Then, this is the same as $$9\cdot 18-156.$$

Comment: 9⋅(330−2⋅156)−156

Where did the -156 come from?

Comment: From $$9\cdot 18-156,$$ we use the top line of your algorithm to substitute $$330-2\cdot 156$$ for $18$. The $-156$ from the first expression remains untouched and we arrive to $$9\cdot(330-2\cdot 156)-156.$$

Answer (score 1):

I like to write these as [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction), rather than "back-substitution"

$$  \gcd( 330, 156 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 330 }{ 156 } = 2 +  \frac{ 18 }{ 156 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 156 }{ 18 } = 8 +  \frac{ 12 }{ 18 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 18 }{ 12 } = 1 +  \frac{ 6 }{ 12 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 12 }{ 6 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 6 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 & & 2 & & 8 & & 1 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 17 }{ 8 }   & &   \frac{ 19 }{ 9 }   & &   \frac{ 55 }{ 26 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 55 \cdot 9 - 26 \cdot 19 = 1 $$

$$  \gcd( 330, 156 ) = 6  $$
 $$ 330 \cdot 9 - 156 \cdot 19 = 6 $$